# Shifting of the spectrum of a linear operator - in both the symmetric and non-symmetric cases,

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

a) I finished a problem that sort of highlighted the fact that if a real symmetric matrix $A_2$ = A + I, where A is also real and symmetric, then $A_2$ has the same eigenvectors as A, but its spectrum is shifted by 1.  So, if the spectrum of A were {1,2,3}, the spectrum of $A_2$ would be {2,3,4}.

Are the above statements also true for non-symmetric matrices (real or complex)?

b) Also, a quick question about one of the statements of the Spectral Theorem:  it says the vector space V is the direct sum of the eigenspaces (for a normal operator T in complex space or a self-adjoint operator T in real space).  Does this mean *every* vector in V is an eigenvector of T?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: For part (a) there is a theorem which says $\sigma(A+I)=\sigma(A)+I$ for operator $A$. you can say for each matrix eigenvalue can be added by identity matrix!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question a:** The answer to this one is yes.  You can see this by applying the definition of an eigenvalue.  In particular, if $Ax = \lambda x$ for some vector $x$, then $(A + I)x = (1 + \lambda)x$.  Or equivalently, if $\det(A - \lambda  I) = 0$, then $\det([A + I]- (\lambda + 1)I)$ must also be zero.

**Question b:** That's not quite what it means.  What it does mean is that every $v$ can be expressed in the form $v = v_1 + \cdots + v_k$, where each $v_i$ is an eigenvector of $T$. Moreover, the spectral theorem allows us to select $v_i$ so that $\langle v_i,v_j \rangle = 0$ when $i \neq j$.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thanks so much, @Omnomnomnom :)  Have a great night and Happy Holidays!

Comment: Slight nitpick (you know me...): I would formulate point b as every vector$~v$ can be expressed as sum $v_1+\cdots+v_k$ where $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ are eigenvectors for _distinct_ eigenvalues (and $k$ can range from $0$ to the number of distinct eigenvalues). Then this decomposition is unique up to order, and for a normal operator those $v_i$ _will_ be mutually orthogonal. It is not so much about selecting cleverly, but about avoiding to redundantly use two eigenvectors when their sum is still an eigenvector, and can be used instead.